WIFI 6 ghz in Ubuntu 24.04
My WIFI Card is an Intel Corporation WiFi 6 AX200 (rev 1a) - I am able to connect but it is only recognizing the 2.4/5 ghz channels in Ubuntu. How can I get Ubuntu to detect the 6 ghz?
Currently I'm capped out at 170 Mbps per second-ish.

By everything I've researched the 6ghz capabilities work out of the box on Win 11.
